# Fragments not being displayed until touch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an application where I am trying to dynamically load and display posts. I have this in the `onPostExecute` method of an `ASyncTask`.

```
Log.i("Posts", "Displaying Posts");

// Add a new layout to the top of the posts
final LinearLayout refreshLayout = new LinearLayout(HomeScreenActivity.this);
refreshLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
refreshLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
refreshLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
postsLayout.addView(refreshLayout, 0);

// Fill the new layout with the new posts
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

for (Post post : posts) {
    PostFragment fragment = PostFragment.newInstance(post);
    ft.add(refreshLayout.getId(), fragment, Integer.toString(post.getId()));
    lastPostId = post.getId();
}

ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
postsLayout.invalidate();
postsLayout.requestLayout();
```

Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:id="@+id/posts_refresh">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/posts_layout"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

It was working for a while, and then all of a sudden it stopped displaying the posts until I touch the screen. Thoughts?

[Full Code on GitHub](https://github.com/dgrahn/csci578/commits/master/client)

Comment: I'd suggest reworking this to not add separate `Fragment` objects for each "post".  Instead, look at using a `RecyclerView` or even a `ListView` and adapter to manage your data set and create views for the data.

Comment: @goofyz There is no exception.

Comment: Well. This randomly started working again. I'm going to leave the question for posterity.